# How do I press alt <numpad> with pyautoguii?

Tags: python, pyautogui, numpad

Here's my script:

```
import pyautogui
import subprocess
import time

#notepad is in the file path
programma = "Notepad"

#opening notepad
subprocess.Popen(programma)

#gives time to open notepad, ie I've also tried with higher numbers
time.sleep(1)

pyautogui.keyDown('NumLock')
#I've also tried with 
pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'num3')
```

I've tried and the Numpad works: if I comment the take out 'alt' and just write 
         `pyautogui.press('num3')`
it types the number 3.
Although if I put alt in the code, it gives an error, as if I were typing without having the cursor set.
I've also tried

```
pyautogui.keyDown('alt')
pyautogui.keyDown('num3')
pyautogui.keyUp('num3')
pyautogui.keyUp('alt')
```

Does anyone know what to do?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Working for me:

```
pyautogui.keyDown('alt')
pyautogui.press("num3")
pyautogui.keyUp('alt')
```

If you try to `.keyDown('num3')` pyautogui will think you want to use a third key in your combination.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering my question. I've tried it but it still doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: are you by any chance using a linux distro?

Comment: No, my laptop runs Windows 10 (pro)